# Creating <ul> <li> from MySQL table

Tags: mysql, recursion, html-lists

I am supposed to create a ul li list from this table in mySQL database.

[image]

As below:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About us</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Mission and values</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">History</a></li>

        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">XXXX Department</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">YYYYY Department</a>
</ul>
```

With minimum connection to MySQL.

I was expected to add some more text and delete more codes.
any way like that.

Comment: What framework are you using? ROR, PHP, Node?

Answer (score 0):

```
$items = get_here_all_items();
$res = array();

foreach( $items as $item ) {
    if( $item[ 'parent' ] == '' ) {
       $item[ 'childs' ] = array();
       $res[ $item[ 'id' ] ] = $item;
    }
}

foreach( $items as $item ) {
    if( $item[ 'parent' ] != '' && isset( $res[ $item[ 'parent' ] ] ) ) {
       $res[ $item[ 'parent' ] ][ 'childs' ][] = $item;
    }
}
```

I think you can make HTML from this array. Have fun :)